# Removing # in window hash for use in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have

```
function windowHash() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (window.location.hash == hash) {
        resizePage();
        slide(hash);
    }
}
```

I need to remove the # from the hash var in the if statement.. How would I go about doing this so the slide(); is passed with slide('web-design'); instead of slide('#web-design');

Thanks,

Danny.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var noHash = hash.substring(1);
```

incase you need to add a check for some reason: `if(hash.charAt(0) == '#')`

Comment: no problem, by the way that check will be unecessary as window.location.hash will always start with '#' (just checked). and will return empty if nothing is entered after the '#'.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of javascript `replace()` function which replace the # of your string ...

```
var withouthash = hash.replace('#','');
```

final code for you

```
slide(hash.replace('#',''));
```

Comment: Whenever you want to create a small string from a big one you might want to consider using substring
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp 
instead of just a general replace

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring for those who do not want w3schools

Comment: if you just want to replace # than replace function works fine ........as per his example this will work smoothly